# Laravel fetch data from specific category

Tags: php, laravel, fetch

I`m trying to display data on a blog page side but instead to fetch all the posts in all categories, i would like to have for each single page the category that needed.

For instance: news/entertainment - would have post from entertainment category and so on...

This is the code for fetching all data:

```php
@php
  // use App\post_category;
  use Carbon\carbon;
  if (!isset($posts)) {
     $posts= App\post::latest()->paginate(6);

  }
@endphp
```

tried to replace `latest` with my `category` or do the `post::post_category:entertainment` but not working.

post.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class post extends Model
{
public function post_category(){
    return $this->belongsTo(post_category::class);
}
public function cms_user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(cms_user::class);
}
// public function post_categories(){
//  return $this->hasMany('App\post_category');
// }
}
```

post_category.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class post_category extends Model
{
// public function posts(){
//  return $this->hasMany("App\post");
// }
// public function post(){
//  return $this->belongsTo(post::class);
// }
}
```

postcontroller.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\post;
use App\post_category;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{
public function single($title){
    $post=post::where("title",str_replace("-"," ",$title))->first();
    if ($post!=null) {
    return view('noutati-detaliu',compact("post"));
    }else{
        echo '<h1>ERROR 404, Not Found!</>';
    }
}

public function category($category){
    $category=str_replace("-", " ",$category);
        $cat_id=post_category::where("name","$category")->pluck("id")->first();
    if ($cat_id==NULL) {
        echo "<h1> Invalied Category </h1>";
    }
               $posts=post::where("post_category_id",$cat_id)->latest()->paginate(6);
    if ($posts!=null) {
        return view("noutati",compact('posts'));
      }else{
        echo "<h1>ERROR 404, not found! </h1>";
    }
   }
   }
```

postcategorycontroler.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostCategoryController extends Controller
{
//
}
```

Please advice!

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us the code in the controller, model, etc..

Comment: pleas see edited question with existing setup

Comment: can you please have a look on my settings and see what`s missing?

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to create a category model if haven't already done it

`post_category.php`

```php
public function posts()
{
  return $this->hasMany(post::class); //relationship
}

public function getRouteKeyName()
{
/*  If you would like model binding to use a database 
column other than id when retrieving a given model class, 
you may override the getRouteKeyName method*/
  return 'slug'; 
}
```

then create table for post_category

```php
Schema::create('post_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('slug'); // add this
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

in `post.php`

```
public function category()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(post_category::class, 'post_category_id');
}
```

`posts table`

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_category_id'); // make sure to add this
    $table->string('title');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

`web.php`

```php
Route::get('/news/{post_category}', 'PostsController@index');
```

`PostsController.php` / controller

```php
use App\post_category.php
...
public function index(post_category $post_category)
{
  if ($post_category->exists) {
     $posts = $post_category->posts()->latest()->paginate(6);
  }else{
     $posts = null;
  }
  return $posts;
}
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you find any difficulty to understand it or error

Comment: Okay have updated it, but I didn't update controller name, because you didn't mention it

Comment: would that mess up the current setup? i still need the main news page to show all latest news from all categories. As controller name, what you mean by that? where should i look for it?

Comment: sorry mate, done the changes as you suggested but still not working

Answer (score 0):

First, you should do this in Controller and pass this variable to view

```
$posts = \App\Post::join('post_categories', 'post_categories.id', '=', 'posts.post_category_id')->where('categories.slug', '=', $slug)->select('posts.*')->latest('posts.created_at')->paginate(6);
```

But if i were you i will do this in controller: ($slug - entertainment in your example)

```
$category = \App\Category::where('slug', $slug)->with()->firstOrFail();

$posts = \App\Post::where('post_category_id', $category->id)->latest()->paginate(6);

return view('posts', compact('posts'));
```

Comment: try this too but not working either, so not sure what i`m missing....